# Robot running Linux is slow to boot

Tags: boot, performance

I'm working with a robotic platform (for use in the RoboCup competition) and we run Ubuntu Server 13.10. It's critical during matches that our robots are able to boot as quickly as possible. What's more, if they power cycles during a fall, then the robot has 10 seconds to come back to life before being taken off the field.

Currently the boot time is around 15 seconds and I'd like to know what I can do to reduce that time. Hopefully I can learn something too.

[Here is the full output of `dmesg`](http://pastebin.com/32PQNeE5) which I suppose helps break down what is going on at each time step.
There are a few gaps in the output:

- At 0.41 there's a gap of about 0.8 seconds
- At 3.64 there's a gap of about 2.8 seconds
- At 9.67 there's a gap of about 0.8 seconds
- At 12.9 there's a gap of about 1.4 seconds

`eth` is not required though `wlan` is.

Can anyone decode this into actionable advice for how to get this bot booted faster? And if there is not enough information in these messages, what else might I try to investigate further?

---

**EDIT** I modified my binary (which starts automatically as an upstart job) to write to the syslog. It shows, starting with the first logged message after powered:

```
Oct 30 12:51:52 darwin6 kernel: imklog 5.8.11, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
....
Oct 30 12:52:12 darwin6 kernel: [   34.276716] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Oct 30 12:52:13 darwin6 dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Oct 30 12:52:13 darwin6 dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
Oct 30 12:52:13 darwin6 dhclient: All rights reserved.
Oct 30 12:52:13 darwin6 dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Oct 30 12:52:13 darwin6 dhclient: 
Oct 30 12:52:13 darwin6 dhclient: Listening on LPF/wlan0/00:0d:f0:95:0d:4d
Oct 30 12:52:13 darwin6 dhclient: Sending on   LPF/wlan0/00:0d:f0:95:0d:4d
Oct 30 12:52:13 darwin6 dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Oct 30 12:52:13 darwin6 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x3cd422f3)
Oct 30 12:52:13 darwin6 dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.3 on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3cd422f3)
Oct 30 12:52:13 darwin6 dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.3 from 192.168.0.1
Oct 30 12:52:13 darwin6 avahi-daemon[833]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::20d:f0ff:fe95:d4d.
Oct 30 12:52:13 darwin6 avahi-daemon[833]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Oct 30 12:52:13 darwin6 avahi-daemon[833]: Registering new address record for fe80::20d:f0ff:fe95:d4d on wlan0.*.
Oct 30 12:52:14 darwin6 dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.3 from 192.168.0.1
Oct 30 12:52:14 darwin6 avahi-daemon[833]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.3.
Oct 30 12:52:14 darwin6 avahi-daemon[833]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Oct 30 12:52:14 darwin6 avahi-daemon[833]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.3 on wlan0.IPv4.
Oct 30 12:52:14 darwin6 dhclient: bound to 192.168.0.3 -- renewal in 41314 seconds.
Oct 30 12:52:21 darwin6 ntpdate[1294]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset -0.243167 sec
Oct 30 12:52:46 darwin6 kernel: [   68.451644] perf samples too long (2504 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
Oct 30 12:53:49 darwin6 boldhumanoid[1455]: Starting boldhumanoid process
```

The strange thing is that I also timed with a stopwatch. From turning the power on to my process starting (the robot coming alive) was 35 seconds. It seems that something is causing the syslog write to be delayed by a further 100 seconds, going by the timestamps.

Comment: Did you check `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: @Letizia, nice. I didn't realise that file contained more info than `dmsg`. The output is [here](http://pastebin.com/91pZmgSN).

Comment: What do you mean by boot? Time between clicking some `on` button and time when you see your robot on network?

Comment: @c0rp, the network isn't the primary issue -- it's the time from when I turn the robot on to when it starts walking around. I'm adding some code to write to syslog when my executable starts so I can measure that more effectively.

Comment: You can try to do this: `1` disable IPV6, `2` disable dhcp, use static IP, `3` disable `apparmor`, `4` disable `cups`

Comment: @c0rp, `2` is done (for eth1, not wlan1 -- I'll look into this further). Unsure how to do `1` (Googling). Unsure what implications are of `3` and `4`. The `cups` package is not install, fwiw.

Comment: Could you add output for `service --status-all` and `initctl list`

Comment: @c0rp, for sure. It's [here](http://pastebin.com/JjmmwsLi).

Comment: Here is some related link: [Perf samples too long, lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample rate to](http://superuser.com/questions/757444/perf-samples-too-long-lowering-kernel-perf-event-max-sample-rate-to), [Bug 1013708 - perf samples too long (2506 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1013708), [Bug 1246216 NEW perf samples too long (2519 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000](https://lists.launchpad.net/kernel-packages/msg25082.html)

Comment: In /var/log/syslog there are two "perf samples too long" one at [   64.706641] and the other at [  164.618474]. Did you change link to dmesg log in your question?

Comment: I don't know do need `nginx` and `isc-dhcp-server` , but you can also disable it. And you can safely disable `apport`.

Comment: @Letizia, sometimes I see one, sometimes two. In my edit you see another example with only one instance of that message.

Comment: @c0rp, `nginx` is used, but it doesn't have to block other applications from starting. I don't believe `isc-dhcp-server` or `apport` are explicitly used. Thanks for the tips. I'll research the impact of disabling/uninstalling them.

Comment: @DrewNoakes You should be aware - 13.10 is now End of Life, and while we can't close your question because it was posted prior to it going End of Life, the support for 13.10 is over.

Comment: @ThomasW., thanks for pointing that out. I would like to upgrade them to 14.04, but it causes the hardware subcontroller (a USB device) to fail after a few seconds of use. Now that 14.10 is out, we will try that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if a server installation of Ubuntu is really the right way to go, because of what you are describing sounds like a job for archlinux or similiar to me.

You will need to do a lot of customization on your system, which is when a "take a base system and add anything needed" approach is easier than a "use a full-fledged installation and remove anything unnecessary (e.g. apport, apparmor, dhcp ...)" one.

But anyways, there actually IS a wiki entry all about reducing boot time. The commands may not translate 1to1 for your Ubuntu system, but this entry might point you in the right direction:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Improve_boot_performance

I am sorry, but reducing device-specific boot time is nothing a short answer on askubuntu can handle, you will have to look at every item in your startup routine and decide whether it is necessary or not and disable the system components accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. We may have time in future to look at building a new environment from scratch for the robots, though for now Ubuntu has been convenient, especially as it's the environment we recommend to the first and second year undergrad students on the team. The wiki article looks useful too. I'm keen to check out Arch though, so this may just be enough encouragement. Thanks :)

Comment: zeroconf isn't fast but if that's what you're using then it is what it is. That stall at .41 is the ramdisk loading, you can trim it by editing the files in /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks and running update-initramfs with the proper switches. Again it's a measure, test, and repeat process. @3.69  you're probably waiting on EXT4 journal checking, see if you can minimize that. You could probably do without ipv6 and the associated modules. bootchart may be if use to you, http://www.bootchart.org//

Comment: @ppetraki, thanks, I'll try your suggestions. Bootchart looks nice too.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those applications where you basically start subtracting until you break something and then back off. Like for instance, I don't think your robot is likely using zeroconf which is the avahi daemon, so uninstall it. Do you really need networking? Or better, boot into single user mode (append 1 to kernel cmdline) and then see how many services you have to turn on before your application starts working.

Comment: I've been doing that slowly. We do actually use mDNS (`avahi`) in order to locate our robots on the random networks we encounter when we travel to competitions, league meetups, labs and homes. I'd be happy to replace `wicd` with something easily configurable via flat files. A few attempts at that have come up empty handed. Single user mode is an interesting idea which I'll investigate. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Which size division are you in? I realize this may not be the answer you're looking for here, but for something time critical like standing up within 10 seconds, I would go with an embedded platform.

If you have the space / power budget, you should consider sticking something like an arduino on the robot, and programming some open-loop stand-up behaviors. You can still use ubuntu on the main board. I'd suggest something like this:

- Have an arduino (or similar) that receives a regular heartbeat signal from the ubuntu server
- If more than X heartbeat intervals go by, the arduiono takes control, and reboots the server
- The arduino can directly drive the motors (or through whatever motor controller you're using) and issues a stand-up command, which allows the robot to "recover" and not get disqualified, while your main system boots up

  - Pre-program a few stand-up behaviors, possibly based on which way the robot is facing, and then select one of them based on an accelerometer
  - If you aren't in one of the legged divisions, then just write some cheesy code on the ardiuno to make it look like the robot is doing something while the server boots up
- Once the system boots up, it will send another heartbeat, and the arduino can release control

There are answers here which can help you improve boot time (turn stuff off until you break it, basically), but even then, if loosing power is a common enough problem, something like this could be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. We're in the kid-size humanoid league, so yes they're legged robots of about 50cm in height. The hardware sub controller on the platform is a [Robotis CM-730](http://support.robotis.com/en/product/darwin-op/references/reference/hardware_specifications/electronics/sub_controller_(cm-730).htm) which I believe we can get the firmware source for (perhaps for an old version of it) so perhaps some basic motion could be configured there. That's likely quite a bit of work, though it could be useful for other things like stability.

Answer (score 1):

Try reducing storage buffer to 4 MB. In /etc/sysctl.conf write:

vm.dirty_bytes = 4194304
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 1048576

also maybe reduce writing time to 3 seconds

vm.dirty_expire centisecs = 300
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 300

Please comment if this helped or not. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please explain what these settings are for and why you think it is a good idea to change them?

Comment: These are kernel settings for dealing with memory management. Linux by default uses big buffers for a long time (that is why when a power failure occurs there is a higher chance for data loss). In the Ubuntu forum I found a comment from someone who said somensing along the line that Windows uses smaller buffer for a shorter time and that he did the same to his Ubuntu install and he had better boot performance. IMHO when the buffer is big freezes occur when writing the 30 MB or so at once to disk, and I searched for solution because I  wanted to listen to music from a microSDHC install smooth.

Comment: Also try vm.swapiness = 1 to reduce swap usage (by default which is 60 it uses swap too much, and that means slower).